# Kotlin Performance Issue With RegEx

Tags: regex, performance, kotlin, jvm, performance-testing

I'm making a log parsing app that uses regular expressions and I'm seeing some strange behavior that I'm hoping someone can help explain and perhaps give tips to overcome. First, here's the code:

```
import java.io.File

var regex1Count = 0
var regex2Count = 0
var noMatchCount = 0
val regex1 = Regex(".*error.*", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
val regex2 = Regex("exception|crashed|death|fatal|killed| f | e ", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val file = File("C:\\Users\\pnogas\\Desktop\\mobicontrol.log")
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = file.useLines { sequence ->
        sequence.mapNotNull { line ->
            parseLine(line)
        }.toList()
    }
    println("took ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000.0} seconds")
    println("regex1Count = $regex1Count, regex2Count = $regex2Count, noMatchCount = $noMatchCount")
}

private fun parseLine(line: String) {
    for (filter in listOf(regex2, regex1)) {
        if (filter.containsMatchIn(line)) {
            if (regex1 == filter) {
                regex1Count++
            } else if (regex2 == filter) {
                regex2Count++
            }
            return
        }
    }
    noMatchCount++
}
```

When I run this code it outputs:

```
took 4.198 seconds
regex1Count = 16, regex2Count = 101, noMatchCount = 11559
```

But if I change the one line to listOf(regex1, regex2) instead of listOf(regex2, regex1):

```
took 35.049 seconds
regex1Count = 18, regex2Count = 99, noMatchCount = 11559
```

I understand that the wildcard regex is going to be more expensive to run, but the numbers suggest changing the order only makes it run two times more which seems like it should be negligible compared to the total number of lines processed. I get the same performance if I make the list only contain regex1.

On top of that when I use notepad++ to do the same regex search on the same file I get the 18 results but the result comes practically instantly. I know JVM won't be able to perform as well as native compiled code, but is it really expected to run that much slower. Or am I going about this the completely the wrong way?

**Some clarifications due to responses so far**

1. I agree using "error" instead of ".*error.*" will solve the time issue here. The problem for me is that the string to make the RegEx from will come from user input in the app. I guess one thing I can do in my app is some pre-processing: (e.g. remove any leading or trailing wildcards and leave internal ones)
2. I am aware that since the first RegEx to match returns, the order is important. Again since this will come from user input, I'm okay with putting the responsibility on them to choose a performant order
3. Other tips for performance improvements are welcome, but the main question I want answered here is **why the order makes SUCH a difference in my example**? Unless I'm missing something...

in the first example:
regex2 runs 11676 times (matching 101 times)
regex1 runs 11575 times (not running the 101 times regex2 matched)

in the second example:
regex1 runs 11676 times (matching 18 times)
regex2 runs 11658 times (not running the 18 times regex1 matched)

So regex1 runs 0.86% more times, regex2 runs 0.15% less times, but the runtime increases by 754% ?!
My only random guess there's some sort of JIT JVM Warmup running the simple regex first that allows the second, more complicated one to run faster and I should insert a dummy RegEx that will always be quick before doing the regexes I care about to improve performance...???

Comment: oh, and just in case it's relevant, I'm using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.8.10-hotspot, Kotlin 1.4 with target JVM 11

Comment: Try removing the return statement in parseLine and see if that fixes the order discrepancy.

Comment: For regex one can't you just use `error` instead of `.*error.*`, since you are using `containsMatchIn`, instead of matching the line exactly.

Comment: Your count does not count the number of times your regex has been used , only the number of times it has found a match.

Comment: removing return has no impact (not to mention in the actual app implementation it needs to return an object on each match). I agree using "error" makes the performance way better (as expected) the problem is that these values will come from user input in the app...Lastly, I'm aware what the numbers mean. That's why I have the noMatchCount, to see how many times both ran without a match (I expect that to be where most time is spent)

Answer (score 3):

It's a complex question, so sorry in advance for the long (and sadly incomplete) answer.

There's a misunderstanding with your test code. The first regex in your list will be evaluated on **all** lines, therefore 11676 times in your example. Your regex1Count variable *only* returns the number of times a **positive** match has been returned by the (costly) search operation. So changing evaluation order of you regex can have a *huge* impact on performance, as the first regex will serve as primary filter.

Also, as @PiRocks stated, the regex could be simplified. Even more, due to its simplicity (search of a single word), using regex is not even necessary here. You could perform a literal search, and it would be far far faster.

Also, being a JVM user for years, I have to fix a common misconception about performances : JVM applications are not always slower than native ones. Each technology shines in its own domain, and to get maximum performance is often to pick the right tool for the right task. For example, JVM uses JIT to perform aggressive optimisations of frequently used code, and the garbage collector heavily reduce the cost of variable allocations.

Anyway, in the current case, we **cannot** compare hand-made code performance with a shipped application, whatever technology is used by both end. Why ? Because we cannot be sure to compare equivalent workflow. Here, *maybe* notepad has :

- buffered the entire file in memory,
- created an index before-hand,
- analysed input search regex and removed unneeded complexity before execution,
- multi-threaded the search,
- etc.

I've tried to reproduce your case through kotlin playground:

1. Generate random text lines
2. Testing your `regex1`
3. Comparing the same regex through java pattern api
4. testing `regex2`
5. Performing a literal search for the word "error".

The results are obvious : the literal search is fast lightning compared to the `.*error.*` regex. Regex are a really powerful tool, but they're complexity can be hard to manage.

Now, one question remain : Are JVM regex poorly implemented in term of performance ? To answer that is not simple. Naively, we could try to take the playground I've made (see code below), rewrite it in another language and compare outputs of both. But due to JVM JIT / warmup time, the comparison would be biased.

We'd have to extensively loop over both implementation, gather statistics and *finally* compare results to get a good insight.

*For reference, here is the playground and its output*:

```
Log example :
ex quam Suspendisse  vel sed  rhoncus aliquet. elit.
nibh amet, sed  nibh eleifend diam amet ex eleifend.

Measure Regex on 12000 lines

Regex 1 for 10 words per line took 0.439 seconds
Regex 1 for 20 words per line took 0.843 seconds
Java pattern 1 for 10 words per line took 0.407 seconds
Java pattern 1 for 20 words per line took 1.347 seconds
Regex 2 for 50 words per line took 0.463 seconds
Literal search for 1000 words per line took 0.836 seconds
```

```
import kotlin.random.Random
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.lang.System
import java.util.regex.Pattern

fun main() {
    println("Log example :")
    generateLogs(nbLines = 2, wordPerLine = 10).forEach { println(it) }
    
    println("\nMeasure Regex on 12000 lines\n")
    
    val regex1 = Regex(".*error.*", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    for (nbWords in listOf(10, 20)) {
        roughMeasurement("Regex 1 for $nbWords words per line") {
            val matched = generateLogs(wordPerLine = nbWords)
                .count { regex1.containsMatchIn(it) }
        }
    }
    
    val javaPattern = Pattern.compile(".*error.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    for (nbWords in listOf(10, 20)) {
        roughMeasurement("Java pattern 1 for $nbWords words per line") {
            val matched = generateLogs(wordPerLine = nbWords)
                .count { javaPattern.matcher(it).find() }
        }
    }
    
    val regex2 = Regex("(exception)|(crashed)|(death)|(fatal)|(killed)| f | e ", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    roughMeasurement("Regex 2 for 50 words per line") {
        val matched = generateLogs()
            .count { regex2.containsMatchIn(it) }
    }
    
    roughMeasurement("Literal search for 1000 words per line") {
        val matched = generateLogs(wordPerLine = 1000)
            .count { it.indexOf("error") >= 0 }
    }
}

fun roughMeasurement(title: String, action: () -> Unit) {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    action()
    val end = System.nanoTime()
    val timeSeconds = (end - start).toDouble() * 1e-9
    println("$title took ${"%.3f".format(timeSeconds)} seconds")
}

/* 
 * LOG GENERATION UTILITIES
 */


fun generateLogs(nbLines : Int = 12000, wordPerLine : Int = 50) : Sequence<String> {
    return (1..nbLines).asSequence()
                       .map { generateSentence(wordPerLine) }   
}

fun generateSentence(nbWords : Int) : String {
    require(nbWords > 2) { "Need more than two words per sentence" }
    val builder = StringBuilder(nbWords * 3)
    for (i in 0..nbWords-2) {
        builder.append(wordPool.pick()).append(' ')
    }
    builder.append(wordPool.pick())
    
    return builder.toString()
}

fun List<String>.pick() = this[Random.nextInt(0, size)]

/** 
 * Authorized words in log generation. 
 * To test for worst-case scenario, we've omitted searched keywords: 
 * error exception crashed death fatal killed
 */
val wordPool = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse eu ex eu ligula egestas posuere ac et velit.
Fusce sed nisl diam. Proin eleifend nibh vel felis fermentum,
a luctus diam eleifend. Pellentesque feugiat magna sit amet 
arcu eleifend, vel lacinia justo aliquet. In quam magna, 
rhoncus a lacinia vel.
""".split(Regex("\\s+"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't think there's a misunderstanding. I agree that the order matters, but since the VAST majority of lines have to be evaluated against BOTH regexes (only to find no matches), I would expect the timing DIFFERENCE to have been tiny when switching the order.
I'll also add some clarification to the question about your other points and my aim with this question.